# Azure "Last backup status" diverging from latest "Restore point"

Tags: azure, azure-backup

Azure's Virtual Machine "Backups" blade shows both the "Last backup status" at the top and a list of "Restore points". When the "Last backup status" diverges significantly from the most recent Restore Point, what does that indicate? I.e., should I be concerned?

See picture below. This is now happening on all my VMs, which are all Ubuntu 18.04.

[image: Azure VM Backup Blade]